# Cakephp, doesn`t enter controller on debug

Tags: cakephp

I was wondering if anyone would tell me where does form submit actually goes first? I know it should went inside the controller but for some reason it doesnt. I want to debug it but i don`t know where to start

Comment: What version of CakePHP? Are you using any middleware?

Comment: Im currently using 3.2, Yes I am,,

Comment: Regardless of the version, everything generally goes through the `index.php` in the webroot. In 3.2, the app skeleton for that file does some bootstrapping (`config/bootstrap.php`), then creates a `Dispatcher` object, and calls `dispatch` on it. That triggers some events, and only then finally gets into the actual controller startup, execution, and shutdown. There may also be components that you are loading into the controller which would run their initialization code before the controller action is reached. There's a *lot* that happens before `function index()` gets called!

Comment: I see, i tried debugging it, the before event when being called triggers the bug and i actually fixed it. Thank you for this